# How to do a multi-line any character match including newline character using RegEx in VBA

Tags: regex, vba, excel, string-matching, multilinestring

I am trying to extract some data from XML using regular expression in VBA, by matching start opening and closing tag of an element, but I am not getting anything.

I can use `<foo>.+?<\/foo>` in Notepad++, but its not working in VBA with Microsoft Regular Expression 5.5

```
<foo>
variable data here 
-
-
</foo>
```

Comment: you can try `/<foo>[.\n\r]+?<\/foo>/gm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the . does not include newline in VBA.
You can use (.|\n)* in your pattern definition to include the newline \n
For your example `<foo>(.|\n)*<\/foo>`
You could also use `<foo>[^<]*<\/foo>` if between the foo block you don't expect a <

Answer (score 0):

This is an example to list all the `<td>` contents:

```
Sub MatchXMLtags()
  Dim xml As String
  xml = "<td>a</td><td>b" & vbCrLf & "</td><td>c</td>" & vbCrLf & "<td>d</td>"

  Dim match As Object
  With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .pattern = "<td>\s*([\S\s]+?)\s*</td>"
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .MultiLine = False

    ' display the content of each td tag
    For Each match In .Execute(xml)
      Debug.Print match.SubMatches(0)
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This works quite good for me in MS Word (the only regexp in many dozens I tested), but not exactly how I need: as a starting delimiter I have "##", and that's fine; but my end delimiter is:  **§<space>[text, text, text, text, ,,,]<space>-<space>(text, text, text,...)<end-of-line>**, and I can't figure out how to find it; I can't find even the right regexp for just the end delimiter, my output is *all* the delimiters in the document! I tried with **§ \[(.*)\] - \((.*)\)** and many other variants with no success.